# how to configure ATk4 for two sites to one database

Tags: php, deployment, frameworks, production-environment, atk4

For production environment, i want to have a setup that lets me update the website code but only direct a small number of users to pages with the new code (e.g. myself and whoever logged the bug/enhancement) so my plan is to have a setup like this.

Have two sets of all code online (alpha and beta) but only one database (I realise this means i will have to carefully manage database issues and keep backward compatibility but each change should be relatively small and incremental so think this is ok).

Have a column on the user table which identifies whether they go to the Alpha or Beta code.
When i have completed a code change and done unit testing, the code will be uploaded to the Beta site and i will test it online so only my user will be directed to the Beta site.

Once i have tested, set the user who raised the issue/enhancement request to use the Beta site so they can test it by logging in.  Once confirmed, apply the code update to the Alpha site and do one final test. That release is then complete.

Users who do not login will only have access to the Alpha site.

Because the first access to user information is in Frontend.php, whats the best way to do this - do i need to have two API (Frontend.php) and if so, how can i decide which of these should be loaded based on the user ?

The aim is to ensure that updates to production dont cause an issue for all users so if anyone has any suggestions as to how they manage code deployment to avoid this, all suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create 2 environments, side by side. APIs would check user preference and redirect the user between those environments. I probably wouldn't go as far as to mix classes together or try to keep same URL for the sake of clean versioning control.

Comment: So you recommend i use two different URLs e.g. mysite.com and test.mysite.com but both have the same config-default.php so they use the same database. Then I extend the auth module and modify so that when the user logs in, check my custom column and then redirect to the appropriate base URL - right ?